# Difference between CDDL (Suns OS License) and GPL

Tags: licensing

- What are my obigations if used by commercial software ?
- Is it GPLish or closer to ASL 2 ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)bout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IANAL, but the FSF [has stated](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#SoftwareLicenses) that the CDDL is incompatible with the GPL. In terms of linking, it seems to have some features of the LGPL (linking from code with a different licence is allowed).

I'd read the [legal text](http://www.sun.com/cddl/cddl.html) very carefully and check with your company's lawyer. Any changes you make to the code itself will have to be CDDL'd as well.

Comment: Do you mean any changes to the cddl code has to be returned (aka lgpl) ?

I will reread the license a few times

Comment: Yes. It is copyleft, in that if you make a change and distribute it you have to include the source of the original as well as your modification.

Comment: What about any *linked* code - aka the viral asspect of GPL ?

Comment: From the way I understand it, you can link code under any license to CDDL code.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this page via a person asking about the dual licensing of Sun (now Oracle) software under both GPL and CDDL. What this means is that you are free to use the software under the terms of one license or the other, or (as what most people seem to be doing) carry on the dual licensing for downstream users.